# How to generate build for android mobile?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I have installed PhoneGap in my mac and I am able to select PhoneGap project template using Xcode. Now I my doubt is, how can I deploy the application on Android device?

Do I need to set up Eclipse and need to install PhoneGap Sdk again?

Can't I develop it on one platform and get the build for other mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to configure cordova on seperate platforms if you download the libraries.
Although you can use https://build.phonegap.com/

To just write code once and you will get the respective installable files for the mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above answer. But if you keep developing apps using Phongap you better you Install ecplipse and sdk. Then add following plugin

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/

It will generate you entire set up  for application. You need to replace www folder.
Make your you also replace correct cordova js file. Because it needs to be the one created for Android.